# Why does server returns 500 response to post request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download file from [steamworkshopdownloader.io](https://steamworkshopdownloader.io/) with requests but it always returns 500 error. What am I doing wrong? I am not very familiar with requests.

Code:

```
import requests

def downloadMap(map_id):
    session = requests.session()
    file = session.post("https://backend-02-prd.steamworkshopdownloader.io/api/details/file", 
        data={"publishedfileid": map_id})
    print(file)

downloadMap("814218628")
```

Comment: `500` means that the server did something weird. Maybe your sending to the wrong server.

Comment: Check this url "https://backend-02-prd.steamworkshopdownloader.io/api/details/file" in your browser and see if the server is up and running.

Comment: Please use `session.get(...)` to send a get request to a server to download files

Comment: If you want to download a file from this site look at https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/396698-steam-workshop-downloader/code they are using different URLs to yours and the URLs they use give 200 OK responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download a file from this API try this code, it's adapted from the link in the comment I posted earlier (https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/396698-steam-workshop-downloader/code) and converted into Python:

```
import requests
import json
import time

def download_map(map_id):
    s = requests.session()
    data = {
        "publishedFileId": map_id,
        "collectionId": None,
        "extract": True,
        "hidden": False,
        "direct": False,
        "autodownload": False
    }
    r = s.post('https://backend-01-prd.steamworkshopdownloader.io/api/download/request', data=json.dumps(data))
    print(r.json())
    uuid = r.json()['uuid']
    data = f'{{"uuids":["{uuid}"]}}'
    while True:
        r = s.post('https://backend-01-prd.steamworkshopdownloader.io/api/download/status', data=data)
        print(r.json())
        if r.json()[uuid]['status'] == 'prepared':
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    params = (('uuid', uuid),)
    r = s.get('https://backend-01-prd.steamworkshopdownloader.io/api/download/transmit', params=params, stream=True)
    print(r.status_code)
    with open(f'./{map_id}.zip', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

download_map(814218628)
```

The code demonstrates how to use the API and downloads a file named 814218628.zip (or whatever `map_id` was provided) into the directory the script is run from, the zip archive contains the .udk file (Game map design created by the Unreal Engine Development Kit).